# How to write .htaccess 301 redirect rule?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to 301 redirect some urls. Here is what i need to redirect

http://www.site.com/?var=  to  http://www.site.com/
and
http://www.site.com/123/folder/page.html?var=  to http://www.site.com/123/folder/page.html

Comment: Try following the suggestions in the SO editing guide http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. This will make your question easier to read and understand.

Comment: So you actually just want to remove `?var=`, right?

Comment: yes i just need to remove the ?var=

Answer (score 1):

redirect 301 /about.php http://www.kintek.com.au/about

Note the first half uses only the page location

```
redirect 301 /about.php
```

And the redirection is the full url

```
http://www.kintek.com.au/about
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the right code:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} var=
RewriteRule (.*)  http://www.example.com/$1?  [R=301,L]
```